# How to get values from a hidden field that is created in forEach with different values?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I’ve been working with jquery recently. I need to remove parameters from hidden fields that are created through forEach, that is, under class = "productID", the values ​​are different. How do I click on the button to take the value only from the desired hidden field.

```html
<div id="successAdded" style="color: green">
  <h3>${sessionScope.successAdded}</h3>
</div>
<c:forEach items="${sessionScope.allProducts}" var="products">
  <div class="col-md-4 fashion-grid">
    <a href="single.jsp"><img src="images/product/${products.imageName}" width="250" height="350" alt="" />
      <div class="product">
        <h3>PRODUCT NAME:</h3>
        <input type="hidden" class="productID" value="${products.id}">
        <span class="getName">${products.name}</span>
        <p>${products.size}</p>
        <p>${products.color}</p>
        <p>${products.category.name}</p>
        <p>${products.manufacturer.name}</p><br></br>
        <p><span></span>${products.price}</p>
      </div>
    </a>
    <div class="fashion-view"><span></span>
      <div class="clearfix"></div>
      <input type="button" class="addProductToCart" style="margin-top: 50%;" value="Add to cart" />
    </div>
  </div>
```

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  $('.addProductToCart').on('click', function getPage() {
    var id = $(this).find('.productID').val();
    alert(id);

    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "cart",
      data: "productID=" + id,
      success: function(page) {
        $("#header men").text(page);
        $("#productCount").text("(" + page['productCount'] + ")");
      }
    });
  });
```

I get undefined value in my implementation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two issues here. Firstly, the hidden element has a `class` on it, so you need to prefix the selector with a `.`, eg. `.productID`.

Secondly, you're using `find()` from the clicked button to find the hidden field, yet it's not a child of this element. Instead it's a child of a parent's sibling. As such you need to combine `closest()`, `prev()` and `find()` to retrieve it, like this:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  $('.addProductToCart').on('click', function getPage() {
    var id = $(this).closest('.fashion-view').prev('a').find('.productID').val();
    console.log(id);

    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "cart",
      data: { productID:  id },
      success: function(page) {
        $("#header men").text(page);
        $("#productCount").text("(" + page['productCount'] + ")");
      }
    });
  });
});
```